# How to Read Related Data Using LINQ/C# [one to many]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two related tables with one to many relationship, I m trying to get a `JSON` response that populates `ICollection<PatPar> PatPar` the controller's code below reads fine as long as I have only one related record, once I have more than one related record I get a selection exception.

These are related `Models`

```
public class PatReg
    {
        [NotMapped]
        private Int64 _FileId;
        [Key, Display(Name = "File Id"), ScaffoldColumn(false), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public Int64 FileId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._FileId;
            }
            set
            {
                this._FileId = value;
            }
        }
        [Required, Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PatPar> PatPar { get; set; }

    }


public class PatPar

    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 RecId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Patient File Id"), Required]
        public Int64 FileId { set; get; }
        [Display(Name = "Partner File Id"), Required]
        public Int64 ParFileId { set; get; }
        [Display(Name = "Start Date"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), Required]
        public DateTime SDate { set; get; }
        [Display(Name = "End Date"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? EDate { set; get; }

    }
```

This is my `API Controller`

```
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<PatReg> GetPatReg()
        {
            return _context.PatReg;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPatReg([FromRoute] long id)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var patReg = await _context.PatReg.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FileId == id);
            var parinfo = await _context.PatPar.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FileId == id); // I should select many records here 
            if (patReg == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var DataRes = new {
                sData = patReg                
            };

            return Ok(DataRes);
        }
```

I know that I should use `selectMany` instead of using `SingleOrDefaultAsync` so I tried

```
IEnumerable<PatPar> parinfo = await _context.PatPar.SelectMany(m => m.FileId == id);
```

but the compiler is giving me errors, what is the way to do it?

Comment: If you get a compilation error what is the error?

Comment: `the type arguments for method enumerable selectmany cannot be inferred from the usage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = _context.PatPar.Where(m => m.FileId == id);
```

`SelectMany` is used to retrieve a collection from each item of the iterated collection. However your condition is to check if the `FileId` equals some `id` - the resulted type is a boolean. I assume what you are trying to do is return all the times that have that `FileId`.

To have it with the `await`:

```
var result = await _context.PatPar.Where(m => m.FileId == id).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Returns `Null` and I can't use `await` because it does not contain a def for GetAwaiter

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar - and for sure line above does not return null. Maybe an empty collection but not null

Comment: It worked thanks, without `await` I get this response, it shows `Null` {
 `"sData": {
  "fileId": 1708010001,
  "fName": "Ahmad",
  "patPar": null
 }
}`

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar - This is a followup question.. All I can do is suggest that you have a look at `Include`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want actually this:

```
IEnumerable<PatPar> parinfo = _context.PatPar.Where(m => m.FileId == id);
```

`SelectMany` description:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So it is needed if you want to get `IEnumerable<SomeSpecificField>` as the result.

However, it is applicable only if `PatPar` had `IEnumerable<SomeType>` and you want to `SelectMany<PatPar, SomeType>`.

In your case there can be only `Select`

```
IEnumerable<Int64> parFileIds = _context.PatPar.Select(m => m.ParFileId );
```

Comment: The same error `the type arguments for method enumerable selectmany cannot be inferred from the usage`

Comment: Second option still isn't valid